# Need help updating table from a select query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following code that produces a list of order numbers and values...

```
SELECT 
 d.`OrderNo`, 
 SUM(v.`UnitPrice`)
FROM tblverification v 
LEFT JOIN tblorderdetailsafter d ON v.`VMainID` = d.`MainID`
GROUP BY d.`OrderNo`;
```

I need to update a table called `matcontctsafter` which has an `OrderNo` field and currently blank `InvoiceAmount` column that I need the relative `SUM(v.UnitPrice)` in.

Can anybody help me construct the `UPDATE` clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE matcontctsafter m
INNER JOIN (
SELECT 
 d.`OrderNo`, 
 SUM(v.`UnitPrice`) InvoiceAmount 
FROM tblverification v 
LEFT JOIN tblorderdetailsafter d ON v.`VMainID` = d.`MainID`
GROUP BY d.`OrderNo`
) sq ON m.OrderNo = sq.OrderNo
SET m.InvoiceAmount = sq.InvoiceAmount;
```

Comment: Yup! Thats the one I came up with, took 2 minutes to run on 49,000 records.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE matcontctsafter m SET m.InvoiceAmount = (SELECT 
SUM(v.UnitPrice)
FROM tblverification v 
LEFT JOIN tblorderdetailsafter d ON v.VMainID = d.MainID
WHERE m.OrderNo = d.OrderNo);
```